# How to call update function of web service from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a web service function which is to update my database. I would like to call it from my web application but it won't work. It can be update through my web service but not my web application after I have call my web service. Is my code of calling the service function correct?

Here is my web service update function :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string sell_item(string name, string photo, string description, string initial_price, string bid_time)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=Bidding;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE login SET name = @name, photo = @photo, description = @description, initial_price = @initial_price, bid_time = @bid_time where username='"+ Session["username"] +"'", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initial_price", initial_price);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid_time", bid_time);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return "Product has been upload successfully!";
}
```

This is my web application code that call the function:

```
public partial class bidpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
abc.Service a = new abc.Service();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a.sell_item(Convert.ToString(TextBoxProduct.Text), Convert.ToString(TextBoxPhoto.Text), Convert.ToString(TextBoxDescription.Text), Convert.ToString(TextBoxPrice.Text), Convert.ToString(TextBoxBidTime.Text)));
}
```

}

In my sqlcommand I try to remove the WHERE, my web application can be update data to database, but for all row the data updated are all the same. But when I put back there WHERE statement follow with Session["username"], my update in web application won't store any data.
Any help with this? I really have no idea how to update my data using session.

Comment: @daryal The update process work perfectly when I run my web service. But when I try to call my service function in my web application and click the button, it simply won't update my database table information.

Comment: becoz Session["username"] is null if i m not wrong

Comment: @Tuscan the Session["username"] is not null because there is data in my database for username.

Comment: Put your debugger in the first line of your service. And check whether the debugger come or not. We simply said that check the web service is calling proper or not?

Comment: If it is calling properly then it may be possible that your web method should be static.

Comment: @AzharMansuri It is calling properly. Besides, I have other web method which is for select and insert data into database. It working fine and can be call from my web application. But when it come to update, it won't work. So I'm wondering is my web method update code is correct or is something goes wrong with how I call my web service from my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Add your web service in to your service reference.

It will generate a client.Create a client for your service. And you can access the method through your client.

```
Yourservice.ServiceClient client = new  Yourservice.ServiceClient();
client.SellItem();
```

Comment: I have added my web service in to my service reference. And I follow your code, but I getting error on the namespace CommonServiceClient.

Comment: what is your service name? that was just a sample.

Comment: Yes. I have put in my service name. It is still won't work. When I click the button it won't store my information into my database for what my input of the textbox.

Comment: what are you returning? what does the label1 display?

Comment: supposedly it will return "Product has been upload successfully!" if it work. It seem like my web application couldn't call the sell_item web method, when I press the button from my web application, the label1 did not show the return value.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add a try catch and see if you can catch the exception and return a string if it has an error.